# ¿Cómo actúa la variable "i" en la función (que a mi parecer es recursiva)?

Tags: c

Intenté imprimir la variable dentro de la función y me di cuenta que solo va de 0 a 2 variando. Y no entiendo por qué, ya que cada vez que se llama a la función esta le suma +1.

Esta función recibe un array, la cantidad de elementos del array y un contador que sería la *i*.

```
void perm(int* s, int n, int i){
  int c,j;
  if (i >= n-1) 
  {
      for(c=0;c<n;c++)
      {
            printf("%i",s[c]);
      }
      printf("\n");

  }
  else {
    perm(s, n, i+1);
    printf("%i",i+1);
    for (j = i+1; j<n; j++){
      swap(&s[i], &s[j]);
      perm(s, n, i+1);
      swap(&s[i], &s[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Aunque el tercer parámetro es el que permite que la función recursiva termine, no es en lo único que debes concentrarte. Sino en como reacciona cada instrucción a él. No me queda claro que quisieras saber de `i`. Podría darte un largo ejemplo de que sucede paso a paso pero sería más simple que debugees el código.

Comment: Tu premisa es falsa. La `i` va tomando valores entre 0 y `n-1`, y al llegar a este último es cuando se vuelca la permutación obtenida y se retorna del nivel más profundo de recursión al nivel superior (en el que `i` valía 1 menos).  Pon el print que muestra `i` al inicio de la funcion en vez de dentro del else y haz una prueba con un array de 4 elementos  (sospecho que estabas probando con uno de 3)